# Seam Framework - seam-generator filled with bugs

Tags: java, jboss, seam, seam-gen

I really like seam-generator when is doing it's job well. I think it's a wonderful thing and spare you of a lot of work and problems.But the thing is that it is filled with bugs.

Now I'm generating a project, do some reverse engineering, my CRUD application works and then after anything but a Jboss Restart everything goes apart. I'm getting deployment errors(web.xml could not be deployed and so on).

What am I doing wrong?

By the way I'm using Eclipse Helios, Seam 2.2.1, Jboss Server 5.1GA and Jboss Tools 3.2 for Eclipse Helios.

Comment: You should at least paste full stack trace in your question - without that it is really hard to tell what you are doing wrong.

Comment: In this case it doesn't really matter the stack trace because I just wanna know if there is something wrong with the generator... As long as the application works and after a server restart it crashes than it isn't something that I'm doing wrong. I think...

Answer (score 0):

You say everything goes apart after anything but a JBoss restart, anything like what?  User entry?  Page refreshes? Hot deploying code?  Hot deploying views?  If it's a deployment issue, are you doing a dev build?  That will determine whether you can do deployments on the fly(but only for certain folders).